# Do overridden methods inherit decorators in python?

Tags: python, inheritance, decorator

Just like the title says, do overridden methods inherit decorators?

```
class A:
    @memoized
    def fun(self, arg):
        return None


class B(A):
    def fun(self, arg):
        #computations
        return something
```

so does B.fun() maintain the decorator?

Comment: When you tried it, what did you observe?

Comment: I have to disagree that this is something that deserves a downvote for not trying first. It's a definite question with an unambiguous answer. Using  decorators in inherited methods is completely valid to use if you don't understand how to write decorators yourself.

Comment: "It's a definite question with an unambiguous answer" is completely unrelated to trying it first.  Take the hint.  Try it first.

Comment: Old question I know - martineau's comments are understandable, but I would tend to say that Falmarri's question is still valuable, as SO is about sharing knowledge and making answers easier to find for others. It saves other people's time by not having to write the test code by themselves. I don't think it was worth a down vote.

Comment: I agree with @AlexandreH.  This question saved me the effort from trying it myself.  Shame on the rest of you for being so quick to blast other people who are trying to learn.

Comment: SO is not only about solving the OP's problem, but solving other people's problem as well. Also, he probably wanted to know a way of fixing this behaviour if it didn't work like he expected. So I don't see how this question is of bad quality to the site.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Think about it this way

```
class A(object):
    def fun(self, arg):
        return None
    fun = memoized(fun)
```

Answer (score 7):

No. It's a completely different function. But you can try that for yourself with a dummy decorator.

Answer (score 1):

No, it doesn't.